# Characterization by nets of relatively countable compact set on TVS

Tags: general-topology, compactness, topological-vector-spaces

Let $E$ be a topological vector space and $A \subset E$. How can I prove that $A$ is relatively countable compact if, and only if, every sequence in $A$ has a subnet that converges in $\bar A$.

I know the result just for countable compactness and I've managed to prove the result just for compactness, but in that proof I've constructed a new net in $A$ based on a net in $\bar A$ and a local base for $E$ and  I don't know how to get in that way a sequence instead of a net.

Any ideas?

PD: The forward direction is easy to show. Is the reciprocal the one which I cannot prove.

Comment: Have you considered using characterizations of countable compactness which talk about accumulation points of sequences?

Comment: Yes. That is what I was trying.

Comment: And have you made any progress on that front?

Comment: No. That's why I'm asking it. I've proven the corresponding result for relative compactness but I'm stuck with this one.

Comment: For the forward direction, let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $A$. Since $\overline{A}$ is countably compact, it follows that every sequence in it has an accumulation point. So, $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ has an accumulation point $x \in \overline{A}$. This means that every nbhd of $x$ contains infinitely many points of the sequence. Now, use the directed system of nbhds of $x$ (as well as the definition of an accumulation point) to construct a subnet of this sequence which is defined on this directed system of nbhds of $x$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the forward direction was easy to obtain (as you have showed) is the reciprocal the one which I cannot prove.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to think that the result holds in that direction?

Comment: I've read (with no proof) it is true for regular spaces and every TVS is regular, so it must be true. But I don't find a proof for the regular case neither.